# Where is the X.org config file? How do I configure X there?

Tags: xorg, intel-graphics

As Ubuntu 10.10 seems to neither detect my graphics card (Intel 82852/855GM) automatically nor use the corresponding Intel driver even after manually installing it, I am looking into manually configuring X (shouldn't I?). Where can I find the configuration files I need to edit?

Comment: Even if you come up with a solution, don't forget to file a bug on Launchpad so that this hardware configuration can be made to work out of the box in future Ubuntu releases.

Comment: We deliberately don't load the intel driver on your hardware because it is too unstable.  See this answer: http://askubuntu.com/questions/4658/how-to-install-intel-82852-855gm-driver/4802#4802

Answer (score 95, accepted):

The xorg.conf does not exist by default any more. You CAN create one though.

Boot into recovery mode and select Root Shell. Then run:

```
X -configure
```

Then:

```
cp /root/xorg.conf.new /etc/X11/xorg.conf
```

Reboot and you can edit the new Xorg.conf.

Comment: But if it does not exist, should I really create it? Where are X settings stored by default? Maybe It's better to use the way which is meant to be an actual standard?

Comment: This is the correct way. It is just that X now auto-detects the settings, and a xorg.conf is not mandatory. If you know what you want to edit, by all means create one.

Comment: If X is now meant to auto-detects the settings, can I just tune it up to auto-detect my hardware correctly? In Arch while I had Xorg.conf, I was not to edit it, as X autodetection tool has autodetected everything correctly (from which I conclude it is possible) and generated correct Xorg.conf.

Comment: I am unsure, as I have not messed with it much myself. Though I did once do the auto generation, and added a simple config to enable an intel graphic feature. and everything worked well even though I only put a few things in the conf.

Comment: Thank you. I've done just 2 things exactly as written: 1. installed the driver as written here: http://bit.ly/aBZuAx (which itself is not enough) 2. Created xorg.conf as you wrote (and had nothing to change there). And it works perfectly now. I just wonder why standard boot-time autodetection fails if "X -configure" autodetection works perfect.

Comment: Not sure, though if you believe that you have encountered a true bug, you can report it by pressing alt+f2 and typing:
ubuntu-bug xorg

Comment: There is absolutely **no** reason to reboot even once. Just open terminal, write `sudo X -configure; sudo cp ...` and `sudo /etc/init.d/gdm restart` (assuming Ubuntu, not KUbuntu).

Comment: @Olli; it doesn't work, you need the X server to be inactive for X -configure to run

Comment: Josh G: If you are already running X, just say `X :1 -configure`. You have to open the X server on its own display port; if you already have an X server running, the default port of :0 will fail, so you have to specify display :x (where x is the first available display; in most cases 1).

Comment: When running X :1 -configure I have the error : Number of created screens does not match number of detected devices.
  Configuration failed.
 ddxSigGiveUp: Closing log
Server terminated with error (2). Closing log file.

Comment: @chmike, you may see that error running `X :1 -configure`, but the config file is generated nonetheless. Its location is mentioned in the output. Worked for me.

Comment: That gives me `Could not create lock file in /tmp/.tX0-lock` and no config files.

Comment: could also create a `.xprofile` to set display.

Comment: One a headless VM with Lubuntu desktop, Ubuntu 16.04 LTS the output of `sudo X -configure` says: "No devices to configure.  Configuration failed."

Comment: It doesn't seem like this is a very good solution, considering it completely overrules anything already in /usr/share/xorg.conf.d, though that directory isn't very easy to customize. Seems like every guide I find has 99% repeated information followed by very slightly more information than the last one. Frustrating there isn't a guide of all possible configuration options for xorg in one place.

Comment: This doesn't work at all. It gives me the error "Number of created screens does not match number of detected screens. Configuration failed." This is a laptop. There's only one screen...

Answer (score 69):

The configurations files are at `/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d`

**They are:**

*10-evdev.conf*

*11-evdev-quirks.conf*

*50-vmmouse.conf*

*50-wacom.conf*

*51-synaptics-quirks.conf*

Check the **[current manual](http://www.x.org/releases/current/doc/man/man5/xorg.conf.5.xhtml)**.

If you create a **xorg.conf** file the configurations of this file will prevail.
Also check [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/27017/12943).

Answer (score 23):

Usually, you don't need the `xorg.conf` any more.

If you need to configure some devices anyway, you can do so by placing a file in the `/usr/lib/X11/xorg.conf.d/` (Ubuntu 10.04) or `/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/` (since Ubuntu 10.10). There are some files in this directory already.

You can find more information on [xorg.conf.d](http://wiki.ubuntuusers.de/xorg.conf.d) (in german, but the configuration files are in english of course). What is important is that the filenames should start with a two-digit number greater than 10.

Another guide - in english - is on [x org archive](http://www.x.org/archive/current/doc/man/man5/xorg.conf.5.xhtml). It's still using /usr/lib but it's good.

Comment: Good point and the rigth way to go.  The Arch Wiki also has more on this too (https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Xorg#Display_Size_and_DPI) though their X server is configured to use /etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/ which makes more sense to me.

Comment: In Ubuntu, user-added Xorg options should *also* go into `/etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/` files. You'll have to create that directory first, but it works, and is actually mentioned in Ubuntu's `/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/*` files.

Comment: So many upvotes, but while this answer will *work*, it is still incorrect, IMHO.  The *distribution* places its X configuration files in `/usr/lib/X11/xorg.conf.d`, but [per the Filesystem Hierarchy Standard](https://refspecs.linuxbase.org/FHS_3.0/fhs/ch04.html), *"/usr is [for] shareable, read-only data.... Any information that is host-specific or varies with time is stored elsewhere."*  To override the system config, the host configuration should be in `/etc/X11/xorg.conf` or `/etc/X11/xorg.conf.d` as in the [accepted answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/4663/1165986) and @tanius comment above.

Answer (score 13):

cookiecaper's suggestion to use

```
sudo X :1 -configure
```

worked for me - right from the desktop! It did finally error-out, but not before providing a nice new xorg.conf.new in my Home directory. Thanks cc! All the other suggestions I had tried failed to produce a file.

Oh, by the way,

```
man xorg.conf
```

in the terminal will provide a bunch of useful, and up to date, info (a bit terse, perhaps) on editing the xorg.conf file.

Comment: `X -config /root/xorg.conf.new`

Comment: It removed my second monitor from my PC. No easy fix for that one, so I guess I have to reinstall ubuntu. Nice one.

Comment: @Simon seriously? Did you try to just undo what you did? (ie, remove the /etc/X11/xorg.conf file?) Read desgua's answer, it explains how the newly created xorg.conf will override all other settings for XOrg.

Answer (score 1):

This works fine for me with Nvidia Optimus (Bumblebee) without any special configuration, just the defaults:

```
#!/bin/bash
#
# Source: https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=140315
#

r=`zenity --width 400 --height 250 --title "Display setup" --text "Choose display mode:" --list --column "Modes" "Internal" "External" "Clone" "Extended"`

case "$r" in
Internal)
    xrandr --output LVDS1  --auto \
           --output VGA1 --off ;;
External)
    xrandr --output LVDS1  --off \
           --output VGA1 --auto ;;
Clone)
    xrandr --output LVDS1  --auto \
           --output VGA1 --auto --same-as LVDS1 ;;
Extended)
    xrandr --output LVDS1  --auto --primary \
           --output VGA1 --auto --left-of LVDS1 ;;
esac
```

The monitors LVDS1 and VGA1 are defined in ~/.config/monitors.xml.
For more information about monitors.xml take a look at http://www.sudo-juice.com/dual-monitor-settings-in-ubuntu/.

Example:

```
<monitors version="1">
  <configuration>
  <clone>no</clone>
  <output name="LVDS1">
      <vendor>AUO</vendor>
      <product>0x213c</product>
      <serial>0x00000000</serial>
      <width>1366</width>
      <height>768</height>
      <rate>60</rate>
      <x>1280</x>
      <y>256</y>
      <rotation>normal</rotation>
      <reflect_x>no</reflect_x>
      <reflect_y>no</reflect_y>
      <primary>yes</primary>
  </output>
  <output name="VGA1">
      <vendor>GSM</vendor>
      <product>0x43ff</product>
      <serial>0x00035928</serial>
      <width>1280</width>
      <height>1024</height>
      <rate>60</rate>
      <x>0</x>
      <y>0</y>
      <rotation>normal</rotation>
      <reflect_x>no</reflect_x>
      <reflect_y>no</reflect_y>
      <primary>no</primary>
  </output>
  <output name="HDMI1">
  </output>
  <output name="DP1">
  </output>
  </configuration>
</monitors>
```

Answer (score 0):

Yeah for most free graphics drivers, recent releases of Ubuntu haven't required a xorg.conf file. You can generate one pretty easily though:

```
sudo Xorg -configure
```

Answer (score 0):

For lost amd users: Please note that amd drivers provide a tool to generate xorg.conf

```
aticonfig --initial
```

Comment: `aticonfig` is *proprietary*; it does not install with `xserver-xorg-video-ati`. AMD/ATI users can use `xrandr` to configure displays.

Answer (score 0):

For users running Ubuntu 19.10, I can confirm that adding a configuration file by booting into recovery, selecting root shell, then running:

```
X -configure
```

Then entering:

```
cp /root/xorg.conf.new /etc/X11/xorg.conf
```

will both allow you to edit the configuration file, and fixes the common dual-monitor mouse flickering issue.