# Where is /etc/X11/xorg.conf?

Tags: xorg

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Where is the X.org config file? How do I configure X there?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/4662/where-is-the-x-org-config-file-how-do-i-configure-x-there)

Where is the xorg.conf file in **Ubuntu 10.04**?

I couldn't find it in `/etc/X11/xorg.conf`