# Flash Video Problem -- Is this an Issue with my Intel Video Card?

Tags: flash, intel-graphics

When I maximize flash to full screen mode, it lags.  The video renders slowly even though the sound is playing smoothly.

I think this might be caused by an issue I'm facing with installing the correct video driver for my computer, an "HP dv4 2154ca" .

I've tried to install the driver a couple of times, but the xorg.conf file is still empty no matter what.

So my question is, why is this file empty, and how could I generate it correctly for my device?  Is this the cause of my video rendering problems in flash?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

By default, [there no longer is an xorg.conf file](https://askubuntu.com/questions/5314/where-is-etc-x11-xorg-conf) as everything is autodetected at this point. I can't answer why fullscreen flash is having trouble, based on what I can tell your computer shouldn't have trouble with that.

Answer (score 1):

[This bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/flashplugin-nonfree/+bug/346289) is very possibly the cause of your problem.

From there, you can try the GPU validation trick :

```
sudo mkdir /etc/adobe
echo "OverrideGPUValidation=true" >~/mms.cfg
sudo mv ~/mms.cfg /etc/adobe/
```

But many people have reported that Compiz prevents this fix from working properly, so you might be out of luck until a revised flash-plugin becomes available.

Another option might be to switch to Chromium, as it uses an inbuilt version of flashplugin.  To be honest, that just means that Chromium's flashplugin might be a little more up to date, but ultimately it's still just flashplugin, so possibly a dead end.