# Lost the config of my monitor once I connected it to a KVM switch

Tags: video, intel, switchbox, adapter

I used to have a monitor (Acer 20", AL2017) connected to the external video port of my laptop. Everything was great and I could get a rather high resolution available when setting it under Ubuntu (all versions). But since I connected it to a KVM, the monitor is no more recognized, and I cannot go beyond 1024x768.

My video adapter is an Intel chipset 9xx from an older Pentium Core 2 Duo laptop. The same monitor, using another video chipset (Intel 82G33/G31 rev 02) is properly detected through the switch box.

Looks to me like the video chipset is not the best, and I can live with this. I see that I have no xorg.conf, and I understand that I would need to generate one so I can then use it to force the available modes on the X system.

How can I generate the xorg.conf file for my Intel video chip, so I can use it then ?

Merci :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might want to have a look at this question which has a great answer already;

[Where is the X.org config file? How do I configure X there?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/4662/where-is-the-x-org-config-file-how-do-i-configure-x-there)

Answer (score 0):

Did you got any solution with this thread?
I have exactly the same problem , or almost the same. I have a monitor to expand my laptop's screen. When it is alone connected , it works great. Then I connect it to KVM switch. It still works fine till the system to suspent or to make restart...Then again the resolution is down and the worst is that I can not adjust it to the correct values from the  system display options.
Thank you.