# /etc/X11/xorg.conf doesn't exist?

Tags: intel-graphics, xorg

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Where is the X.org config file? How do I configure X there?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/4662/where-is-the-x-org-config-file-how-do-i-configure-x-there)

I'm trying to get my video card properly setup to handle 3D acceleration. After searching a bit, I've come across a few howtos that tell me I need to edit my xorg.conf file. That file doesn't exist. X.org is installed by default, I'm sure, and I figured this video card would be widely supported.

00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Mobile 4 Series Chipset Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 09)

Any ideas on how I can get this to work properly and play Starcraft II? Or any game for that matter? No resolution problems or anything, just no 3D rendering.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You COULD create your own xorg.conf by typing in a tty (not running gdm) the following:

`X -configure`

That will create a file called **xorg.conf.new**

To test the file type `X -config xorg.conf.new`

If you can load X and see the mouse and a good resolution then you can press CTRL+ALT+BACKSPACE to quit.

Copy then xorg.conf.new to the new location

`cp xorg.conf.new /etc/X11/xorg.conf`

Run `startx` to test.

Also the file does not exist since X.org does not needed anymore for some video cards (as i understand) only some Video cards have xorg.conf because of specific configurations (Like Nvidia and Ati). The rest of the X.org configuration options are in **/usr/share/X11** like synaptics.

Now to test out if you have Direct Rendering do this:

`glxinfo | grep -i "Direct Rendering"` If it says YES then you can run several games. If it says NO then you might need more configuration. Also run `glxgears` to see how many FPS you have. If the glx commands are not there run `sudo apt-get install mesa-utils`

I can not guarantee that it will make it work for starcraft 2 (Remember you also need to have wine installed)

Comment: after some poking around, I found out it's a problem with Starcraft II, not my drivers. Accepted because the answer is relevant to the question, but the question I asked was in fact, the wrong one.

Comment: Thanks for this excellent answer! I had no idea that X had a -configure flag. Is this new?

Comment: "The rest of the X.org configuration options are in /usr/share/X11" This is ridiculously useful information that I haven't seen anywhere else.

Comment: grep -i is better for "testing" direct rendering, since output of glxinfo has that text with lower case, at least on my machine ...

Comment: You have to stop the x server before X -configure.

Comment: I have an error after `X -configure` command: "Cannot establish any listening sockets - Make sure an X server isn't already running"

Comment: @Dr.X Make sure you are not running this from the desktop (or an Xorg based environment)