# 14.04 Parallels and VirtualBox resolution issues

Tags: virtualbox, xorg, display-resolution

I recently installed Ubuntu 14.04 on Parallels and VirtualBox. Been trying multiple methods to fixing the resolution with no luck.

I am running both these VMs on my mid-2013 MBPr:

```
Intel Iris:
  Chipset Model:    Intel Iris
  Type: GPU
  Bus:  Built-In
  VRAM (Total): 1024 MB
  Vendor:   Intel (0x8086)
  Device ID:    0x0a2e
  Revision ID:  0x0009
  Displays:
Color LCD:
  Display Type: Retina LCD
  Resolution:   2560 x 1600
  Retina:   Yes
```

I have tried editing my xorg.icof file (never did exist in /etc/X11/ in the first place) - [/etc/X11/xorg.conf doesn't exist?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/25746/etc-x11-xorg-conf-doesnt-exist)

Tried making sure I added the refresh rate to the file, usually leads to the system not letting me login in.

The resolution seems great when I'm installing Ubuntu for the first time. But the moment I reboot it and it logs into my user. It's stuck in 640x320. It's hard to even get around and change settings since I can't see but a fourth of pop-up windows.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I install Guest Additions in VirtualBox?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/22743/how-do-i-install-guest-additions-in-virtualbox)

Comment: Voting to close as you should install VirtualBox Guest Additions or edit you answer to be about Parallels only. Why did you use the tag bug-reporting? This site is not for reporting bugs, Launchpad is.

Comment: Good to know. I will try the link supplied. I have been messing with this for a week now. I have tried 3 different VM's and all have the same issue. Just frustrating.

Comment: @LiveWireBT 

Well I ran through that link you supplied, managed to get my resolutions to go from 640x320 to 800x600. Still can't get it to accept any new resolution modes by editing the xorg.icof file. Just don't get it.