# External monitor stuck at 1024x768 resolution

Tags: xorg, kubuntu, kde

I'm running Kubuntu 14.04 on a older Toshiba Satellite with the following graphics hardware:

```
 > lspci -vnn | grep -i VGA -A 12
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: Intel Corporation Mobile 945GM/GMS, 943/940GML Express Integrated Graphics Controller [8086:27a2] (rev 03) (prog-if 00 [VGA controller])
        Subsystem: Toshiba America Info Systems Device [1179:ff10]
        Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 16
        Memory at dc100000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=512K]
        I/O ports at 1800 [size=8]
        Memory at c0000000 (32-bit, prefetchable) [size=256M]
        Memory at dc200000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=256K]
        Expansion ROM at <unassigned> [disabled]
        Capabilities: <access denied>
        Kernel driver in use: i915

00:02.1 Display controller [0380]: Intel Corporation Mobile 945GM/GMS/GME, 943/940GML Express Integrated Graphics Controller [8086:27a6] (rev 03)
        Subsystem: Toshiba America Info Systems Device [1179:ff10]
```

On the laptop screen, the resolution is 1280x800. I've hooked up an external widescreen monitor that I know for a fact supports high resolution (well, at least 1440x900). However, when I hook it up to this Toshiba laptop, the maximum I am allowed to set it at is 1024x768.

I have the proper Intel video driver installed and I know the monitor supports more - why can't I set a higher resolution and how do I fix it? I'm not sure if I should mess around with xorg.conf as I hear that might break stuff if I set it up incorrectly.

EDIT

```
> xrandr -q
Screen 0: minimum 8 x 8, current 1024 x 768, maximum 32767 x 32767
LVDS1 connected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
   1280x800       60.0 +
   1024x768       60.0  
   800x600        60.3     56.2  
   640x480        59.9  
VGA1 connected 1024x768+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 0mm x 0mm
   1024x768       60.0* 
   800x600        60.3     56.2  
   848x480        60.0  
   640x480        59.9  
TV1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
VIRTUAL1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
```

The monitor is this: http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16824116066

When I try to manually generate an xorg.conf file, it appears mostly generic. Here are the "monitor" sections.

```
Section "Monitor"
    Identifier   "Monitor0"
    VendorName   "Monitor Vendor"
    ModelName    "Monitor Model"
EndSection

Section "Monitor"
    Identifier   "Monitor1"
    VendorName   "Monitor Vendor"
    ModelName    "Monitor Model"
EndSection
```

Comment: What does `xrandr -q` output for the second monitor resolutions?

Comment: Please see the new edits.

Comment: Can you post the monitor model as well?  Looks like you need to add the resolution and refresh to your `xorg.conf` in order for this monitor to work.  I had to do the same thing to mine.

Comment: Please see the new edits again. I figured I had to manually update something somewhere but I don't see an xorg.conf (and from what I've read, there isn't one) so I'm not sure how to manually set this monitor up.

Comment: The `xorg.conf` file would go into your `/etc/X11/` folder.  Let me see if I can write something up for it.

Comment: Before I write anything up, try following this one and see if your monitor resolutions aren't fixed.  http://askubuntu.com/a/25749/231142

Comment: Thank you for the help. I've generated a new xorg.conf but it looks mostly generic with no details so I'm not sure it worked as it told me "Number of created screens does not match number of detected devices.". I've copied the "monitor" sections to the post.

Answer (score 1):

**Answer is work in progress.**

In the sections of the `xorg.conf`, the area dealing with Monitor1 (second monitor) is where you would put the specifications for what that monitor supports.  It would look something similar to this:

```
Section "Monitor"
    # HorizSync source: xconfig, VertRefresh source: xconfig
    Identifier     "Monitor1"
    VendorName     "Unknown"
    ModelName      "CRT-0"
    HorizSync       30.0 - 82.0
    VertRefresh     50.0 - 85.0
    Option         "DPMS"
EndSection
```

You would change the Sync and Refresh to match your monitor.  I believe the only one needing change would be the `VertRefresh` from 75 to 85.

Then you would need a line supporting the resolution you want in the "Screen" section, so it would look something similar to this:

**NOTE: The below section is from my setup, but the "Screen" section should be there with the Option metamodes line defining the resolution you desire.  I did a little tweaking to try to match your settings the best I could.**

```
Section "Screen"
    Identifier     "Screen0"
    Device         "Device0"
    Monitor        "Monitor1"
    DefaultDepth    24
    Option         "Stereo" "0"
    Option         "metamodes" "LVDS1: 1280x800 +0+0, VGA1: 1280x800 +800+0"
    Option         "SLI" "Off"
    Option         "MultiGPU" "Off"
    Option         "BaseMosaic" "off"
    SubSection     "Display"
        Depth       24
    EndSubSection
EndSection
```