# How do I configurate xorg.config for intel graphics driver on Ubuntu 20.04?

Tags: drivers, xorg, intel-graphics

So I recently switched to Ubuntu, and my second monitor has had an issue of looking washed out. Which I am 80% certain is due to the system decides to give it a shorter range of colors. I read from http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/man4/intel.4.html that I could modify the settings to try and fix that. Although I am uncertain as to where to find it, intensive googling did not get me too far.

```
ls /usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d
```

gives output:

```
10-amdgpu.conf  10-nvidia.conf  10-quirks.conf  10-radeon.conf  40-libinput.conf  70-wacom.conf
```

xserver-xorg-video-intel seems to be installed from the system itself. I am quite stuck here, where exactly would I be looking for this file to modify? Or should I create my own?

Comment: /etc/X11 is where the xorg.conf is you can open with text editor to edit settings and such also here is the ubuntu manuals page for xorg.conf (https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/cosmic/man5/xorg.conf.5.html) also if there is no xorg.conf file you can generate on with "X -configure"

Comment: also the answer at this question is helpful (https://askubuntu.com/questions/25746/etc-x11-xorg-conf-doesnt-exist)

Comment: Ubuntu have these files in `/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d`

Comment: Unless you have very old hardware, you're probably using the modesetting driver (`man 4 modesetting`). Using the Intel driver you mentioned isn't recommended.