# xorg.conf in ubuntu Natty 11.04

Tags: 11.04, xorg

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Where is the X.org config file? How do I configure X there?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/4662/where-is-the-x-org-config-file-how-do-i-configure-x-there)

I am not able to manually configure since I can't find my xorg.conf under /etc/X11/ I read in a forum that it got depricated. Any insights?

Comment: When a question is closed as "duplicate", could we get a link to the original?