# Creating synaptics entry in xorg.conf cases X to not start

Tags: 11.04, xorg, gdm, synaptics

Ubuntu 11.04 doesn't seem to have an entry for my Synaptics Touchpad xorg.conf file by default.

As soon as I create

```
Section "InputDevice"
    Identifier  "Synaptics Touchpad"
    Driver  "synaptics"
EndSection
```

then GDM fails to start at all.

What is the propery way for me to enter an option for my Synaptics touchpad in xorg.conf?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, a *Related Questions* link answered my question:

[xorg.conf in ubuntu Natty 11.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/37761/xorg-conf-in-ubuntu-natty-11-04)

I just added the settings I wanted to the existing file `/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/50-synaptics.conf`, and it worked. :)