# missing Xorg.conf in Kubuntu 11.04

Tags: xorg, kubuntu

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Where is the X.org config file? How do I configure X there?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/4662/where-is-the-x-org-config-file-how-do-i-configure-x-there)

I am new to Kubuntu 11.04 and needs some helps from you guys. I tried to modify Xorg.conf so I can get my logitech trackball mouse to work properly in kubuntu. As far as I know, the path to Xorg.conf is /etc/X11/Xorg.conf. However, I couldn't find it there.

Anyone knows where it is or what I should do next? Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The file `xorg.conf` is no more required for the configuration of the X server, that can do a very good job automatically.

Anyway you can create your own `xorg.conf` file if you need custom configuration.

You can have a little help in creating a basic `xorg.conf` file with the command

```
sudo X -configure
```

that will generate a file `xorg.conf.new` in your home. Edit as needed, rename it and move it to the correct location.