# where is the xorg.conf file in kubuntu 11.10?

Tags: kubuntu

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Where is the X.org config file? How do I configure X there?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/4662/where-is-the-x-org-config-file-how-do-i-configure-x-there)

How do I edit the xorg.conf file, when there isnt one in Kubuntu 11.10?

I want to alter the video driver, but how do i do this in 11.10? The reason is that i believe I am having issues after a recent upgrage in 11.10, and now my desktop effects no longer work when using the OpenGL compositing, even with the functionality checks disabled...

however, is there a way to alter this file and have they moved it to a new location?

Any ideas?

thanks

Comment: What driver are you using? What graphics processor/chip/card do you have?

Comment: There might not be such a file, you need to create it from scratch. Try `sudo updatedb` and then `locate xorg.conf`.

Comment: Found the issue. 

I read that in 11.10 the xorg.conf file has gone?

When I updated it installed the Nvidia driver, this seemed to screw up my intel driver. I removed all Nvidia references in synaptic package manager (plus any other video driver) and 

Removed the following packages:
libgl1-mesa-swx11

Installed the following packages:
libgl1-mesa-glx (7.11-0ubuntu3)

Rebooted and my issue resolved... Thanks for your responses... much appreciated :-)

Comment: the file usually resides in `/etc/X11/` directory, but only if your Graphics driver has created it, if its not, you need to create it manually like @queueoverflow said.