# my ubuntu 12.04 has no xorg.conf is that normal?

Tags: 12.04, xorg, multiple-monitors

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Where is the X.org config file? How do I configure X there?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/4662/where-is-the-x-org-config-file-how-do-i-configure-x-there)

I have a problem with dual monitor  that I posted in bugs  here `https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/992778`

but I noticed my Ubuntu 12.04 has no **xorg.conf** is that normal?
there is just a directory called **xorg.conf.d**

```
/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d
/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/10-evdev.conf
/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/11-evdev-quirks.conf
/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/11-evdev-trackpoint.conf
/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/50-synaptics.conf
/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/50-vmmouse.conf
/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/50-wacom.conf
/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/51-synaptics-quirks.conf
/usr/share/man/man5/xorg.conf.5.gz
/usr/share/man/man5/xorg.conf.d.5.gz
```

has Ubuntu 12.04 got ridden of `xorg.conf` or it is a error only with  me?