# 12.04 Resolution Changes on Lock + KVM

Tags: resolution, kvm-virtualization

I'm running Ubuntu 12.04 and using a monitor that I share with a Windows laptop via a KVM.  When I login to Ubuntu my resolution is 1900x1200, but when I use the KVM to toggle over to my laptop and then Ubuntu locks, when I KVM back my resolution is set super low.  When I open "Displays" it automatically corrects my resolution back to 1900x1200, and the resolution is fine if I use the KVM to toggle back to Ubuntu before it locks.

I've seen the suggests [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/191647/kvm-switch-and-screen-resolution-problem) post with suggestions on either creating a bash script to set resolution (which seems hacky) or using X settings in xorg.conf, but my symptoms seem different than the ones described in that issue so I didn't want to just blindly try those suggestions.

Help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I've had this same problem on 13.04 and 13.10.  I tried a number of different potential fixes with no luck until I finally gave up.  Well, I just upgraded to 14.04 LTS and this particular bug has been squashed!

You won't be able to upgrade from 12.04 to 14.04 directly until 14.04.1 is released.  At least, not using the standard upgrade options.  If you want to force it to update now, first back up all of your important data, then run `sudo do-release-upgrade -d`.