# Trying to disable touchpad while typing, but messed up libinput vs. synaptics configurations (Ubuntu 16.04)

Tags: xorg, touchpad, configuration, synaptics

First-time Ubuntu user. Using 16.04 on an XPS 9360.

Briefly, I want to disable touchpad while typing.

Have followed a lot of advice on these pages, including:

1. Synaptics was already there (xserver-xorg-input-synaptics-hwe-16.04)
2. Installed touchegg (I also wanted to have three-finger gestures)
3. Installed libintput (xserver-xorg-input-libinput-hwe-16.04)
   (based on [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/886092/how-do-i-disable-the-touchpad-while-typing))
4. Fooled around with configuration files (had to create a new folder etc.) based on [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/578734/how-do-i-implement-a-change-in-xorg-conf-when-i-dont-have-one)

In this process, I lost both my keyboard and touchpad functionality, and had to go into root mode to undo some of the earlier changes. I got the touchpad back, and had to make some more installation changes (lost track of those) to get the keyboard back.

Now, I want to again make an attempt to correctly configure libinput, and remove synaptics (is that the right approach?), but I am afraid of changing configuration files or losing access to my desktop again. Any advise will be super helpful.

Following information might help. Let me know if I can provide more details. Appreciate the help!

```
$ xinput list
⎡ Virtual core pointer                      id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ DLL082A:01 06CB:76AF Touchpad             id=11   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad                id=17   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎣ Virtual core keyboard                     id=3    [master keyboard (2)]
    ↳ Virtual core XTEST keyboard               id=5    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=6    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Video Bus                                 id=7    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=8    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Sleep Button                              id=9    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Integrated_Webcam_HD: Integrate           id=10   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Intel Virtual Button driver               id=12   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Intel HID events                          id=13   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Intel HID 5 button array                  id=14   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Dell WMI hotkeys                          id=15   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ AT Translated Set 2 keyboard              id=16   [slave  keyboard (3)]
```

---

```
$ dpkg -s xserver-xorg-input-synaptics-hwe-16.04
Package: xserver-xorg-input-synaptics-hwe-16.04
Status: install ok installed
Priority: optional
Section: x11
Installed-Size: 179
Maintainer: Ubuntu X-SWAT <ubuntu-x@lists.ubuntu.com>
Architecture: amd64
Version: 1.9.0-1ubuntu1~16.04.1
Replaces: xorg-driver-synaptics, xserver-xorg-input-synaptics
Provides: xorg-driver-input, xorg-driver-synaptics, xorg-renamed-package, xorg-renamed-package-hwe-16.04, xserver-xorg-input-synaptics
Depends: libc6 (>= 2.15), libevdev2 (>= 1.3), libx11-6, libxi6 (>= 2:1.2.0), libxtst6, xorg-input-abi-24, xserver-xorg-core-hwe-16.04 (>= 2:1.18.99.901)
Suggests: gpointing-device-settings, touchfreeze
Breaks: kde-config-touchpad (<< 0.8.1-2~)
Conflicts: xorg-driver-synaptics, xserver-xorg-input-synaptics
Description: Synaptics TouchPad driver for X.Org server
 This package provides an input driver for the X.Org X server to enable
 advanced features of the Synaptics Touchpad including:
 .
  * Movement with adjustable, non-linear acceleration and speed
  * Button events through short touching of the touchpad
  * Double-Button events through double short touching of the touchpad
  * Dragging through short touching and holding down the finger on the touchpad
  * Middle and right button events on the upper and lower corner of the touchpad
  * Vertical scrolling (button four and five events) through moving the finger
    on the right side of the touchpad
  * The up/down button sends button four/five events
  * Horizontal scrolling (button six and seven events) through moving the finger
    on the lower side of the touchpad
  * The multi-buttons send button four/five events, and six/seven events for
    horizontal scrolling
  * Adjustable finger detection
  * Multifinger taps: two finger for middle button and three finger for right
    button events. (Needs hardware support. Not all models implement this
    feature.)
  * Run-time configuration using shared memory. This means you can change
    parameter settings without restarting the X server (see synclient(1)).
  * It also provides a daemon to disable touchpad while typing at the keyboard
    and thus avoid unwanted mouse movements (see syndaemon(1)).
Original-Maintainer: Debian X Strike Force <debian-x@lists.debian.org>
```

---

```
dpkg -s xserver-xorg-input-libinput-hwe-16.04
Package: xserver-xorg-input-libinput-hwe-16.04
Status: install ok installed
Priority: optional
Section: x11
Installed-Size: 105
Maintainer: Ubuntu Developers <ubuntu-devel-discuss@lists.ubuntu.com>
Architecture: amd64
Version: 0.25.0-0ubuntu1~16.04.1
Replaces: xserver-xorg-input-libinput
Provides: xorg-driver-input, xorg-renamed-package, xorg-renamed-package-hwe-16.04, xserver-xorg-input-libinput
Depends: libc6 (>= 2.7), libinput10 (>= 1.5.0), xorg-input-abi-24, xserver-xorg-core-hwe-16.04 (>= 2:1.18.99.901)
Conflicts: xserver-xorg-input-libinput
Description: X.Org X server -- libinput input driver
 This package provides the driver for input devices using libinput library.
 It can handle keyboards, mice and touchpads, and essentially replaces the
 separate -evdev and -synaptics drivers.
 .
 This package is built from the X.org xf86-input-libinput driver module.
Homepage: https://www.x.org
Original-Maintainer: Debian X Strike Force <debian-x@lists.debian.org>
```

---

```
$ dpkg -s touchegg
Package: touchegg
Status: install ok installed
Priority: optional
Section: misc
Installed-Size: 184
Maintainer: Kubuntu Developers <kubuntu-devel@lists.ubuntu.com>
Architecture: amd64
Version: 1.1.1-0ubuntu1
Depends: libc6 (>= 2.14), libgcc1 (>= 1:4.1.1), libgeis1 (>= 2.0.1), libqt4-xml (>= 4:4.5.3), libqtcore4 (>= 4:4.7.0~beta1), libqtgui4 (>= 4:4.5.3), libstdc++6 (>= 4.1.1), libx11-6, libxtst6
Description: Multitouch gesture recognizer
 Touchégg is a cross-platform multitouch gesture recognizer
 that allows associating actions to each gesture.
Homepage: http://code.google.com/p/touchegg

$ ls ~/../../etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/
70-synaptics.conf
```

---

```
$ ls ~/../../usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/
10-amdgpu.conf  10-quirks.conf  11-evdev-quirks.conf      30.libinput.conf  51-synaptics-quirks.conf  70-wacom.conf
10-evdev.conf   10-radeon.conf  11-evdev-trackpoint.conf  40-libinput.conf  70-synaptics.conf
```

---

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure about what to do to restore your system configuration but in order to disable your touchpad, laptop computers usually have a native special key combination. (with the blue FN key). (On my Toshiba laptop, it's the FN+F9 combination)

Comment: Not looking to disable. Just disable-while-typing. Need a fundamental fix, which probably involves uninstallinng / reinstalling one of the packages - synamptic or libinput.