# How to generate an xorg.config on Ubuntu 16.04.1

Tags: 16.04, xorg

We've been trying all the techniques to generate an xorg Config on Ubuntu 16.04.1 but have not had any luck. Has anyone figured out how to do this on the lates Ubuntu 16.04?

Here are things we've tried:

[Where is the X.org config file? How do I configure X there?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/4662/where-is-the-x-org-config-file-how-do-i-configure-x-there)

Comment: If you have NVIDIA drivers installed, I believe you run `nvidia-xconfig` from the command line to create a xorg.conf.

Comment: What was the problem with original answer there?

Comment: Hi anwar, We've been trying the original answers, they don't work. We are using NUC5i5MYHEs so no nvidia utilities.

Answer (score 1):

You could install the NVIDIA linux driver from the nvidia webpage which will ask you to generate the xorg.conf during installation. To do that:

---

Determine your card:

```
$ lspci -vnn | grep VGA
```

and check for your card details. On my system i get the following output running the above command:

```
$ 03:00.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: NVIDIA Corporation GK110GL [Quadro K6000] [10de:103a] (rev a1) (prog-if 00 [VGA controller])
```

So you see im using a Quadro K6000.
Head over to [NVIDIA Drivers entry page](http://www.nvidia.com/Download/index.aspx) and search the proper driver for your card:

[image: NVIDIA search based on lspci -vnn | grep VGA]

Click search and download the driver to your desktop.

The do the following to install the driver:

- switch to console mode: Alt+Ctrl+F1
- kill x server: sudo service lightdm stop
- switch to desktop: cd ~/Desktop
- make the downloaded driver executable: sudo chmod a+x
  NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-367.44.run
- install it with sudo rights: sudo ./NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-367.44.run

During the installation answer YES when you get asked if the installer should generate the xorg.conf file.

---

If you already have the nvidia packages installed from the repositories user Terrance comment is fine