# Ubuntu unusable after trying to update to 16.04

Tags: boot, drivers, nvidia, upgrade

I tried to update my Ubuntu 14.04 to 16.04 and in the middle of the process the computer suffered a power down.

After turning it on again it was unstable, for example the screen wasn't the right resolution.

Trying to solve that I did run `sudo apt-get update` but the problem persisted. Also the top bar disappeared.

Then I tried to change the nvidia default drivers, selecting from the XOrg to another option. I didn't take a screenshot.

After that I couldn't access Ubuntu again. I tried turning the computer on again and getting into recovery mode, and the screen gets frozen and dead.

I tried rescatux as well, in order to fix GRUB in case it was an issue with that.

Now I have the computer turned on with the 14.04 live CD. I do have the hard drive mounted.

Is there any way to access any file in that drive and modify it in order to undo the selection of that Nvidia driver?

Or is there anything else that I could try?

**Please take into consideration that I cannot access Ubuntu, so I cannot type anything into the terminal.**

Comment: I've tried that, but it assumes that I can log in into ubuntu. I cannot access the terminal.

Comment: Then use a LiveUSB to back up your data, then install fresh. A release-upgrade is the most vulnerable time for a system, and poweroff in the middle of it is sometimes simply unrecoverable (or not worthwhile). Users on laptop battery are specifically warned about the risk of power loss when they begin a release-upgrade.

Answer (score -2):

You can revert your Xorg.conf (possibly under /etc/X11/) file to its previous state to use default nvidia driver & boot into it, then try using aptitude to see if you can get the package manager to a more stable state. Reverting is a vague term here. May mean using a backup copy of it if there's one, or just creating a new one (see the link in the update below).

Also, since aptitude works in console mode, you can try booting to console mode from grub to do the same, but you'll need to fix the Xorg.conf before you can get the xwindows.

update:

This answer is downgraded, possibly because there may not be an xorg.conf file. I thought since you tried to install non-default nvidia drivers, you may have ended up with an xorg.conf. Regardless, have a look at another answer for xorg.conf: [Where is the X.org config file? How do I configure X there?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/4662/where-is-the-x-org-config-file-how-do-i-configure-x-there)

Remember, since you're mounting your linux partition from a live-cd, your root partition is mounted somewhere. If, for example it's /media/Linux, than you would be checking /media/Linux/etc/X11/ folder to find it, if it exists.

Comment: "You can revert your Xorg.conf (possibly under /etc/X11/) file to its previous state" How may I do that?