# How to enable "AllowIndirectGLX" on Ubuntu 18.04 with Nvidia (1050Ti)

Tags: nvidia, 18.04, graphics, ssh, xorg

Following scenario: I like to a run an opengl application from a remote cli only server (with a matrox graphics card) through "ssh -X". My local machine is running Ubuntu 18.04 with Nvidia graphics. I've google'd around and found, that I need to enable "AllowIndirectGLX" locally. Unfortunately I've not found how to do this the right way.

There seem to be two possibilities: 
1. Adding '"AllowIndirectGLX" = "on"' to some xorg.conf.
2. Adding "+iglx" as a launch parameter to Xorg command.

Problems with this: There is no "xorg.conf" under "/etc/X11". The only file that comes near this is "/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/10-nvidia.conf". For solution 2 my best guess is "/usr/bin/Xorg". But maybe I need to set this for the GDM configuration?

I would like to avoid endless trail and error sessions. Hopefully you guys can help out!

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned in @NightwishFan's answer to [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/4662/where-is-the-x-org-config-file-how-do-i-configure-x-there), you have to create a xorg.conf file.

*"Boot into recovery mode and select Root Shell. Then run:*

`X -configure`

*followed by*

`cp /root/xorg.conf.new /etc/X11/xorg.conf`
"

Once you have rebooted, open this newly created xorg.conf file using any text editor (use sudo if needed) and add

`Section "ServerFlags"
    Option "AllowIndirectGLX" "on"
    Option "IndirectGLX" "on" 
EndSection`

[This](https://devtalk.nvidia.com/default/topic/1038770/linux/glx-app-crashes-with-remote-ssh-ok-locally/) is an NVidia thread that you might find useful.

Hope it helps.

Comment: putting the above config snippet into `/etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/10-indirectglx.conf` and restarting X works as well.