# Monitor won't display at native resolution.

Tags: xorg, graphics, intel-graphics, resolution, screen

Whenever i connect my monitor to my laptop, it won't display the video at the native resolution in Ubuntu, but my monitor works fine and does both in Windows 7!

In Ubuntu it just gives me stripes and the image "dances, so if i lower the resolution of the monitor, video displays just fine. I've tried the monitor on my Netbook and it works. Both the Netbook and my Laptop i'm connecting to have an Intel "GMA 950 graphics card".

I've tried Kubuntu, Arch Linux, Mint, and Fedora and they all have the same issue, regarding the monitor resolution, whereas it continues to work fine in Windows 7.

Comment: What model of monitor is it, and what is its native resolution? What is the exact GMA950-based chipset on each computer?

Comment: i have the same issue and setting the resolution manually fixes it. Problem is I have to do it every time I start up.

Answer (score 1):

Try setting a lower frequency and/or [updating drivers](https://askubuntu.com/questions/4658/how-to-install-intel-82852-855gm-driver/4659#4659). I've used to have this problem with old (up to this July) drivers and the workaround was to set an external monitor to 60 Hz (by default it was set up to 75 Hz). While lowering resolution as you do is not a pleasant solution, lowering frequency usually makes no visible difference unless you use a CRT display.